# Transformation of the dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transformation

Input DataFrame

| Name Std | Savings | Expense |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100000 | 500000 |
| B | 200000 | 600000 |
| C | 300000 | 700000 |
| D | 400000 | 800000 |

Output DataFrame

| Student1 | Student2 | Student1E | Student2E | Student1S | Student2S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 500000 | 600000 | 100000 | 200000 |
| A | C | 500000 | 700000 | 100000 | 300000 |
| A | D | 500000 | 800000 | 100000 | 400000 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.assign` to assign a broadcasted version of one of the rows as columns to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Your df here
student_label = 0        # The `Name Std` entry in the input df you want to broadcast as columns

renamer = lambda i: {"Name Std": f"Student{i}", "Savings": f"Student{i}S", "Expense": f"Student{i}E"}
sorter = lambda x: x.str[8:] + x.str[7]

out = (
    df
    .assign( **df.loc[student_label].rename(renamer(1)).to_dict() )
    .drop(student_label)
    .rename(columns=renamer(2))
    .sort_index(axis=1, key=sorter)
)
```

out:

```
  Student1 Student2  Student1E  Student2E  Student1S  Student2S
1        A        B     500000     600000     100000     200000
2        A        C     500000     700000     100000     300000
3        A        D     500000     800000     100000     400000
```